# Can I create nodes along the path in this case?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, tikz-path, tikz-positioning

Take this example from [the doc](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#autosec-3039):

```tex
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node foreach \name/\angle in {a/0,b/90,c/180,d/270}
        (\name) at (\angle:1.5) {$\name$};

  \path[->] (b) edge            node[above right]  {$5$}     (a)
                edge                                         (c)
                edge [-,dotted] node[below,sloped] {missing} (d)
            (c) edge                                         (a)
                edge                                         (d)
            (d) edge [red]      node[above,sloped] {very}
                                node[below,sloped] {bad}     (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I was wondering if I can adapt it to my usecase, where the nodes are positioned relative to each other, so it'd be ideal if I could use the `++(x, y)` syntax.

I was thinking about something like this:

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] (0, 0) grid (4,8);
  \path[->] (0, 0) edge +(1, 2) node[at end] (a) {a}
          ++(1, 2) edge +(1, 2) node[at end] (b) {b}
          ++(1, 2) edge +(1, 2) node[at end] (c) {c}
          ++(1, 2) edge +(1, 2) node[at end] (d) {d}
          ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but it looks like the `node`s are insensitive to `at end`; if I put `at start` nothing seems to change either.

[image]

My idea is that they would be between the end of one arrow and the start of the following, but with the arrow heads and tails having enough spacing from the nodes, just like it happens in the linked example.

**I'm interested in whether it's possible to do this with just the `\path` command.**

---

Fwiw, the goal, eventually, is to be able to do something like this, with all the arrows staying on a single line and "passing though" the node's boxes.

```
(It's upside down, but I can't bother re-doing the ascii art, sorry.)
\
 \
  \
   \/|
    \|
 +----------+
 |   foo    |
 +----------+
        \
         \
          \
           \/|
            \|
         +----------+
         |   bar    |
         +----------+
                \
                 \
                  \
                   \/|
                    \|
                +----------+
                |   baz    |
                +----------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An edge node needs to be between `edge[<options>]` and its target coordinate:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0, 0) grid (4,8);
\path[at end, ->] (0, 0) edge node (a) {a} +(1, 2)
                ++(1, 2) edge node (b) {b} +(1, 2)
                ++(1, 2) edge node (c) {c} +(1, 2)
                ++(1, 2) edge node (d) {d} +(1, 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(I've removed the redundant `at end` statements.)

But I don't think this is what you want.

A node is a separate from the path its placed on and will not take interrupt the path where it is placed. You will need to create a node first and then connect a path to it with the usual means.

Since you want more than one arrow tip you will also need multiple paths connecting the nodes. (The `edge` path operation internally creates extra paths.)

And yes, you can do this all on one `\path` if needed:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz
\node         (a) {a}
 ++(1,2) node (b) {b}
 ++(1,2) node (c) {c}
 ++(1,2) node (d) {d}
 [->] (a) edge (b)
      (b) edge (c)
      (c) edge (d);
\end{document}
```

The relative placement could have been done differently.

Also, instead of three edges the `graphs` library can be used:

```
\graph[use existing nodes, path, ->] {a, b, c, d};
% or
\graph[use existing nodes, path, ->] {\foreach \n in {a, ..., d}{\n}};
```

For this simple example it's a bit much but it might come in handy for more complex versions.

Answer (score -1):

All the options below work.

`edge` seems to be special:
[image: citation]

To have arrows passing from node to node as you sketched, no matter where the nodes are, you must define their coordinates first AND have one `\draw[->]` statement each: the arrow is added at the end of the path, not at stops in between. That's why you see only one arrow from my code.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines] (0, 0) grid (4,8);
    \draw[->]  (0,0) 
                    to node[at end] {a} (1,2)  
                    to node[pos=.3] {b} (2,4)
                    to node[at start] {c} (3,6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines] (0, 0) grid (4,8);
    \draw[->]  (0,0) 
                    to node[at end] {a} ++(1,2)  
                    to node[pos=.3] {b} ++(1,2)
                    to node[at start] {c} ++(1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] (0, 0) grid (4,8);
  \draw[->] (0, 0) -- +(1, 2) node[at end] (a) {a}
          ++(1, 2) -- +(1, 2) node[midway] (b) {b}
          ++(1, 2) -- +(1, 2) node[at start] (c) {c}
          ++(1, 2) -- +(1, 2) node[pos=.3] (d) {d}
          ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear, but with _the arrow heads and tails having enough spacing from the nodes_ I mean that I want something like in the ASCII art above, i.e. the arrows should not start from or end into the true center of the node, but should honor the inner/outer sep.

Comment: Plus I don't see intermediate arrow heads at all in your example.

Comment: Kindly read "To have arrows passing from node to node as you sketched, ..."

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read because the image spoke by itself. Now I understand. But still, I don't see how it is an answer to my question, considering that in both snippets I showed my intention to draw a single `\command` and create all the stuff along it as needed.

Comment: Kindly EDIT and refine your question to make it easier to help you. Please remember, this site is not intended for discussions, like other fori. Thank you.